# Using IN with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, multiple-columns

Just a quick question. I'm using single values manually inputed by the user and doing an SQL query comparing to two columns, like:

```
SELECT col3,col1,col4 FROM table WHERE
col1='SomeReallyLongText' OR col2='SomeReallyLongText'
```

The repetition of SomeReallyLongText is tolerable, but my program also supports looping through an Excel document with several hundred rows - which means I'll be doing:

```
SELECT col3,col1,col4 FROM table WHERE
col1 IN('item1','item2',...'itemN') OR col2 IN('item1','item2',...'itemN')
```

And the query would be exhaustively long, which I can't imagine is efficient.
**Is there a way to shorten this** so two columns can be compared to the same IN(xxx) set?

If not, are there other (more efficient) ways of giving the set of values in the query?

(I'm using C# with .NET 4.0 Client Profile, using Excel Interop to access the file)

Comment: You can use a table valued parameter to pass arrays of things, and not just with `DataTable`s and stored procedures http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too sure about the performance you'd get with this:

```
SELECT col3,col1,col4 FROM table
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (VALUES
        ('item1')
        , ('item2')
        , ...
        , ('itemN')
    ) AS It(m)
    WHERE It.m IN (col1, col2, ...)
)
```

Comment: can the `VALUES(('a'),('b'),('c')...('n'))` be shortened, maybe to something like `VALUES('a','b','c'...'n')`?

Comment: Those aren't the same so not with this approach.

Comment: Picked your answer as it doesn't involve creating a new table on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temp table to store all the values used inside the `IN` clause

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Sample') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Sample

Create table #Sample
(name varchar(20))

Insert into #Sample
values
('item1'),('Item2'),....

SELECT col3,col1,col4 FROM table WHERE
col1 IN ( Select name from #Sample) OR col2 IN(Select name from #Sample)
```

or if you are using `Linq to SQL` then you can store the excel data in collection and use `Contains` method to query the DB

```
var excelVal = new string[] { 'item1','item2'... };
var result = from x in Table
             where excelVal .Contains(x.Col1) || excelVal.Contains(x.Col2)
             select x;
```

Comment: Try executing the first 3 lines twice in the same session. You will get "There is already an object named '#Sample' in the database." error